# Swift 4 Delegates - what about more than 1 implementer?

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

Swift 4:
Given: 1 protocol & 2 different classes that implement it, both of them are instantiated.

A third class, instantiated, needs to 'use' the functionality defined in the protocol.
How can I control which of the 'implementing' classes is called through the protocol by the third class?

Comment: What have you implemented yourself ? Show your progress so that we can help you.

Comment: "needs to 'use' the functionality defined in the protocol". Protocols do not provide the functionality, it just declares what can be done. The concrete class(es) define the functionality so. Can you show code usage example?

Comment: It's a little unclear. Do you have a more explainable example? Do you want that both classes reacts to the same delegate call? Or are they separate like `UITableViewDatasource` & `UITableViewDelegate`? Or do you want to have an array of delegates?

Answer (score 0):

first create a delegate.

```
protocol YourCustomDelegate {
    func foo()
}
```

Your third class should have a delegate property like this:

```
class YourThirdClass {
    var delegate = YourCustomDelegate? // this will be either the first or the second class. 
}
```

The creator of the class should set the delegate.

```
class YourSecondClass {
    init() {
        thirdClass = YourThirdClass()
        thirdClass.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Them implement the protocol. I use an extension for more structured code. you could implement this in the YourSecondClass itself aswell.

```
extension YourSecondClass: YourCustomDelegate {
    //implement the functions
    func foo() {
        print("Foo")
    }
}
```

Do the same for the first class.

The class that currently uses YourThirdClass should set itself to be the delegate. If you want to use those simultaneously, add two delegate properties to YourThirdClass. However, if more than one class needs to be updated, consider using notifications.